# list group with scroll in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

i have a razor view with this list:

```
<div class="list-group" id="product-filter-data">
                <div class="list-group-item row text-left">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 text-left">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" value="option1"> All
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 m-l-l text-left">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-tiny btn-default" id="check-none" value="select none">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="list" style="max-height: 300px;" class="overflow-y-scroll">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                    {
                        <div class="list-group-item row">
                            <div class="col-sm-1 text-left">
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="IdContainers" value="@item.IdContainer"> Select
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <a class="media-left" href="@Url.Action("Product", "Container", new { id = item.IdContainer })">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Image)
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading product_name">@item.DisplayName</h4>
                                    @Html.Raw(item.Description)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

My problem is that the result is not lined up the first row with the scrollable ones.
[image]

Is there a way that the scroll keep the alignment?

Comment: Would it help if you put <div id="list" ...> outside of its container <div class="list-group" id="product-filter-data">. Perhaps that could help with the alignment.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?  The only alignment issue that I see is the "select none" button and the images.